# composer dump-autoload and composer update not working

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I run command `composer dump-autoload` or `composer dump-autoload --optimize` it shows error:

> Could not scan for classes inside "App/database/migrations"

This does not not appear to be a file nor a folder so I try to update composer:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.2.1)
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.3.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/var-dumper (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v3.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/translation (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/translation (v3.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/routing (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/routing (v3.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/process (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/process (v3.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/http-foundation (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v3.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.1.1)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/debug (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/debug (v3.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/http-kernel (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v3.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/finder (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/finder (v3.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/console (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/console (v3.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing league/flysystem (1.0.22)
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.24)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing laravel/framework (v5.2.32)
  - Installing laravel/framework (v5.2.39)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing mockery/mockery (0.9.4)
  - Installing mockery/mockery (0.9.5)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/css-selector (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v3.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/dom-crawler (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v3.0.7)
    Loading from cache

  - Removing sebastian/exporter (1.2.1)
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.2)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.0.2)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.2)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.4)
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (3.1.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing phpspec/prophecy (v1.6.0)
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.6.1)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing symfony/yaml (v3.0.6)
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v3.1.1)
    Downloading: 100%

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "App/database/migrations" which does not
  appear to be a file nor a folder
update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
 [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--wi
th-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap
-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i
|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

`composer.json` file contains:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "App/database/migrations"
```

Comment: If you don't have a folder called "App/database/migrations", just remove it from "classmap".

Comment: i have folder app/database/migration .

Comment: it is also present in composer.json

Comment: but dump-autoload is not scanning ap/database/migration

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same case in the composer file as you have on the file system.

If the folder is called: "app/database/migrations" (with a lower "a"), then the `classmap` should be:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/database/migrations"
```

On most file systems, "app/database/migrations" and "App/database/migrations" aren't equal.